# analyze constrained extremum by projection to tangent space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, constraints, tangent-spaces

I want to analyze the local behavior of a function $f(\mathbf{x})$ on a manifold at a certain point $\mathbf{x}_0$ which lies on the manifold.

One approach would be to add small disturbances $\mathbf{h}$ to $\mathbf{x}_0$, project $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}_0 + \mathbf{h}$ onto the manifold (closest point $\mathbf{x}'$ on the manifold), and check whether e.g. $\Delta f = f(\mathbf{x}') - f(\mathbf{x}_0) < 0$ for all $\mathbf{h}$ which would indicate a local maximum.

However, it may be difficult to analytically find the projection $\mathbf{x}'$ on the **manifold**. Therefore I thought of projecting $\mathbf{x}$ onto the **tangent space** of the manifold at $\mathbf{x}_0$ instead.

My question is: If I can show that $f$ e.g. has a local maximum at $\mathbf{x}_0$ on the **tangent space**, can I conclude that it also has a local maximum on the **manifold**?

(Edit: There seems to be an additional difficulty besides the question whether locally the (smooth) manifold can be represented by its tangent space for this analysis: If we derive an expression for $\Delta f(\mathbf{h})$ e.g. at a local maximum, we will always see $\Delta f(\mathbf{h}) = 0$ at the direction normal to the manifold at $\mathbf{x}_0$, i.e. for $\mathbf{h}' = \mathbf{0}$. I wonder whether this can be eliminated afterwards.)

Comment: What about a different approach: Find a parameterization of the tangent space and show that the function has e.g. a local maximum on the tangent space. Would that also prove that is has a local maximum on the manifold? (In my case I deal with a Stiefel manifold for which the parameterization is known: http://math.mit.edu/~edelman/publications/geometry_of_algorithms.pdf)

Comment: The method (small steps on tangent space instead of on manifold) doesn't seem to work. At least for one example function it failed both in an analytical derivation and in a numerical simulation. Test steps on the manifold lead to $\Delta f$ with different signs compared to test steps on the tangent space. I wonder why...